# How to call method from a controller to another controller appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I'm build an application with appcelerator-studio.

The application create programmatically a table with this code:

**controller.js**

```
    var rowData = [];

    var header = Alloy.createController('result_row_header',{
        examination:Titanium.Locale.getString(lang+"examination"),
        start_date:Titanium.Locale.getString(lang+"start_date"),
        end_date:Titanium.Locale.getString(lang+"end_date")
    });
    var viewHeader = header.getView();


    //DISEGNO LA TESTATA
    rowData.push(viewHeader);

    $.table.setData(rowData); 

function set_fields(lang) {
    header.changeLanguage(lang);
}
```

**result_row_header.js**

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

$.examination.text = args.examination;

$.start_date.text = args.start_date;

$.end_date.text = args.end_date;


function changeLanguage(lang){
    $.examination.text=Titanium.Locale.getString(lang+"examination");
}
```

Now I want to call the changeLanguage method from controller.js but if I try to execute the method set_fileds (from controller.js) I have an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little change in your code:

***result_row_header.js***

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

$.examination.text = args.examination;

$.start_date.text = args.start_date;

$.end_date.text = args.end_date;

// this is the code to access function of a controller from any other
$.changeLanguage = function (lang){
    $.examination.text=Titanium.Locale.getString(lang+"examination");
};
```

Rest of your code remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Lets says that this is your view.js file:

```
$.yourMethod = function() {

    return 'first';
};

$.view.yourMethod = function() {

    return 'second';
};
```

And this is your view.xml:

```
<Alloy>
    <View id="view">
        <Label text="test view"/>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

You call it like this:

```
var view = Alloy.createController("view",{});

view.yourMethod(); //will return first

win.add(view.getView());
```

But if you get the view at the creation method, you call it like this:

```
var view = Alloy.createController("view",{}).getView();

view.yourMethod(); //will return second

win.add(view);
```

[Titanium Alloy Controller Constructor doesn't exposer functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533973/titanium-alloy-controller-constructor-doesnt-exposer-functions/37542037#37542037)